# PHP/MYSQL match a sentence against keywords?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a text that can be a 255 chars long.
And I have a db containing keywords.
Is there a way in PHP or MYSQL to test the sentence in order to find matching keywords? (kind of like StackOverflow does suggesting tags after typing the question)

eg.the text is:

> The New York Times: Find breaking news, multimedia, reviews & opinion
>   on Washington, business, sports, movies, travel, books, jobs.

and say my mysql DB contains `newspaper, news, book.`

I'm not sure where to start... what is the best approach?

Comment: What about [`LIKE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)?

Comment: [MATCH()... AGAINST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) is your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to do the opposite of [fulltext indexing functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). Your database contains keywords, not a body of text to search.

So it's not going to work to use `MATCH () AGAINST()`. That searches for keywords in the database.

You can fetch keywords from your database into your PHP script, and then compare the keyword to your text with PHP string functions.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT word FROM keywords");
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll()) {
  if (stripos($text, $row["word"])) {
    $found = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

Or

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word SEPARATOR '|') AS pat FROM keywords");
$row = $stmt->fetch();
if (preg_match("/{$row['pat']}/i", $text)) {
    $found = true;
}
```